# Custom action item ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to add some custom actions into my `ActionBar`, Is it possible to implement these actions with a custom layout? Because I want to add some badge like notification counter to these actions.

e.g

[image]

Any idea to how accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, from XML you can set an arbitrary layout as the action view:

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_refresh_progress"
  android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_progress"
  android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

But since presumably you want to update the badge to something current, you can also set an arbitrary view if you're creating the menu by hand in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    MenuItem someMenuItem = menu.getItem(R.id.menu_option_id);
    someMenuItem.setActionView(theView);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, But one thing I do not understand - how can I update the badge through code?

Comment: I assume it will be part of your layout (a TextView), so inflate the layout and set the value in the TextView for the badge to whatever you want.

Comment: @dmon, Great option, I created the way you instruct. But now I'm updating text value from my fragment which is called in FragmentActivity, and hopefully able to log the value.
Now, my question is that how could I reflact that specific value to my SherlocActionbar which is implmented in my parent FragmentActivity?